# Chromedriver version older than installed

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

I am using Selenium for e2e tests with jest.

I am using chrome version 85.0.4183.121 and have the right chromedriver version available in my PATH: when I type `chromeversion -v` in the command line I get `ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689})`

However, when I build the webdriver to run tests, I get the error `SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74`, as if I had chromedriver 74 installed.

I've seen similar issues but nothing that solved my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the [release notes](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) for that driver say it supports Chrome 85. So I'm presuming your not using the driver you think you are. Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another Chromedriver binary in the Repository, which was actually being used.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem: There was a chromedriver.exe in the project itself, so the tests were using that instead of the one in my PATH. Makes sense, so everyone uses the same version. I replaced that with the correct chromedriver and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome browser and chrome driver exe are updating time to time so you need to use exact chrome driver exe according to your chrome browser version , please check your chrome browser version and download suitable version of chrome driver exe from [chromedriver download link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

There are 2 ways to overcome this

first one is you need to use latest chrome driver exe for your version of browser 85
second is you need downgrade your browser version , First one is proper way of this issue

Comment: I have the correct chromedriver version in my PATH (see my problem's description), and I did it following the Selenium guide (so what appears in my PATH should be the right version). I think the question is where could be this chromedriver 74 located? In the code I looked for all insances of `chromedriver` as well as the 74... version. Nothing.

Downgrading chrome is far from ideal, partly because I won't be the only one using this code.

Comment: You dont need downgrade chrome browser version , please check your browser version and you need to use chrome driver exe according to your version of browser you can download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score -2):

If execution result is telling you:

```
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
```

Then download chromedriver of 74 version and then run it.

Comment: Why would I dounwload chromedriver 74? And if you mean downgrading chrome to 74, I want to avoid that.

Comment: Why don't you try it